# Getting the image file from the server and converting it to base64 using nodejs express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to create a function which gets the exact image file from the server and then converting it to base 64 and lastly storing it to a variable.

**Note: Exact image file (no need to loop through the directory to list all files).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the [image-to-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-base64) library.

**Installation**

```
npm i image-to-base64
```

**Usage**

```js
const imageToBase64 = require('image-to-base64');
//or
//import imageToBase64 from 'image-to-base64/browser';

imageToBase64("path/to/file.jpg") // Path to the image
    .then(
        (response) => {
            console.log(response); // "cGF0aC90by9maWxlLmpwZw=="
        }
    )
    .catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error); // Logs an error if there was one
        }
    )
```

---

**Displaying an image using base64**

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

Comment: Tried this, but all it does was transform the path of the image to base64 and not the image itself.

Comment: seems to be transforming the image to base64 when I try it. I added `img` tag usage in my answer